# Flutter build failed with exit value 1

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to build my Flutter app, but I am getting the following error:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1159
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

I have tried the following things to fix the error, but none of them have worked:

- Running `flutter doctor` to check for any missing dependencies.
- Running `flutter clean` to clear the build cache.
- Deleting the `.gradle` and `.m2` folders in my project directory.

I am running Flutter version 3.3.0 and i did lot of things to solve this issue but still i can't resolve this error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can check all these

1. Check for any errors in your dart file which maybe causing this issue.
2. Check if you have any `assets` and not mentioned in `pubspec.yaml` or maybe a typo.
3. Go to `pubspec.yaml` and run `pub-get` & `pub-upgrde` and check for any outdated packages, if they exist run this - `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`